# How Can I Get Urdu Fonts?

Tags: fonts

How can I use Urdu fonts in Ubuntu?

Comment: I haves same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You must enable `IBus`..  From there there is an Urdu virtual keybooard available ...
You can very simply switch from the English keyboard and fonts, to the Urdu keyboard and fonts .. You can choose your own shortcut key for this.

IBus Preferences can be found in the Main Menu.. System.. Preferences

eg. Urdu script: ااپ کایسع ھہ
or Devanagari: आप कैसे हो

It is very easy to switch from one language's script to another..  The Urdu keyboard entry is based on the phonetic sounds (so is the Hindi/Devanagari).. I don't know if I got the Urdu right, but I've typed the same keys as for the Hindi... and I think for this case is would be about the same ...

Answer (score 1):

STEPS:

1. install all Urdu fonts available in package repos.
2. For Firefox, this problem can be solved by setting the Urdu (Nakash/Noori/Nastaleeq etc.) fonts as default fonts for Arabic.

In FireFox, Edit - Preferences - Fonts & Colors - Advanced - Fonts for:

Now select Arabic (instead of Western), and select Serif=Nakash, Sans-serif=Nakash (or instead of Nakash any Urdu font).

*And most important* Uncheck the box: "Allow pages to choose their own fonts".

Comment: As you're answering a reputation 1 user, a `sudo apt-get install fonts-nafees fonts-paktype' would have been nice.  Please edit your answer as I don't speak Urdu and don't know if my command is what you're trying to accomplish. ;-)
@user13347: Don't mind me: this is a comment to the poster of the question.

Comment: Also review my edits and adapt to your needs!  ;-)